# game button animation lag with Photon

Tags: unity, animation, online, photon

Friends, I am making games using photon. But I could not do the delay animation as described in [this link](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-server-reconciliation.html).

The action appears to be late on the player according to the ping. Can you give an ideas about this?

Comment: So what did you try and where exactly did you encounter something that causes you problems?

Comment: @Zibelas I tried to delay the action of the player (on him) when the button was pressed, but on the other user the action again seems late.

Comment: [There are some additional links at the bottom of this answer that might have some useful insights for you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160709/39518) - the Halo Reach GDC talk in particular goes into some depth on their strategies for handling communication delays in different actions.